# How can i define make_pyramid in line 11 without changing the structure of this program

Tags: python, function, nameerror

when I run the code gives back `name 'make_pyramid' is not defined`:

```
from cs50 import get_int

while True:
    print("Height: ", end="")
    h = get_int("")
    if h < 0 or h > 10:
        print("height must be between 0 and 10")
    else:
        break

make_pyramid(h)
```

I know I can just rewrite this code above but if i did not want to do so, what else can i do?

```
def make_pyramid(h):
    for i in range(0,h,1):
        for j in range(0,h - 1 -i ,1):
            print(" ", end="")
        for k in range(0,(i * 2) + 1, 1):
            print("#", end="")
        print("")
    return
```

Comment: If the `make_pyramid` function is provided for you in the `cs_50` package, then you forgot to import it: `from cs50 import make_pyramid`. Otherwise, you should [define this function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) yourself before you can use it.

Comment: Is make_pyramid function in different module from your main program?

Comment: @JoboFernandez no

Comment: @VladimirFokow wrote this function myself in the same file

Comment: @PrashantGc, in that case simply place your function definition **before** you use it, and it should work! I just checked it myself. Also, you can specify `end="\n"` instead of `end=""` for your tower to start at the new line.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you didn't define `make_pyramid` before you used it, it has to be like:

```
def myfunc():
 ...

myfunc()
```